# Facet won't change colour for alternative plots in function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating a function to wrap up my histogram so its generalisable across multiple datasets and scenarios. However, the colour coding for my alternative plots are not working properly.

I think what happens is that my function assigns the colours to the facet variable and not to the assigned variable for color.

For example:

```
edgeHist <- function(data, x, y = NULL,type=NULL, ...) {
  if (is(y, 'character') & is(..., 'character')) {
    x <- parse(text=x)
    y <- parse(text=y)
    z <- parse(text = ..1)
    gp <-
      ggplot(data, aes(eval(x),
                       group = eval(z))) + stat_summary(
                         aes(
                           y = eval(y),
                           fill = eval(z),
                           color = eval(z)
                         ),
                         fun = 'sum',
                         geom = 'bar',
                         colour = 'black'
                       ) + theme_bw() +
      theme(
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA),
        legend.position = "bottom") + 
      xlab(substitute(x)) + ylab(substitute(y)) +
      scale_fill_continuous(name = (title = substitute(z)))
    

    if(is(type, 'character')){
      if(type == 'single'){
      return(gp)
    }else if (type == 'multiple'){
      z2 <- parse(text=...elt(1)[2])
      gp_plus <- gp + facet_wrap(~eval(z2), scales='free') 
      return(gp_plus)
    }
    }
    return(gp)
    
  }else stop('Stop HERE!')
}

edgeHist(mtcars, 'cyl', 'hp',type='multiple',c('cyl', 'am'))
```

Produces the following:
[image]

Whereas, If I take the chunk of code that I am using for multiple plots, such as the following:

```
gp <-
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl,
                   group = cyl)) + stat_summary(aes( y = hp,fill = cyl, color = cyl
                     ),
                     fun = 'sum',geom = 'bar',colour = 'black' ) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA),
    legend.position = "right") + 
  xlab('cyl') + ylab('hp') +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = (title = 'cyl')) + 
  facet_wrap(~eval(am), scales='free')
```

I get a working plot:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `z <- parse(text = ...elt(1)[1])` instead of `z <- parse(text = ..1)`?

Comment: @Bas that has done the trick! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your function works with the modification suggested by Bas, you are mixing a combination of base R and tidyverse-type non-standard evaluation. It may be better to stick to the tidyverse style to make use of its succinct syntax, and the ability to pass column names without having to pass them as strings. This also avoids some ambiguity in the way your column arguments are parsed at present.

```r
edgeHist <- function(data, x, y, color, facet_x, facet_y) {
  
    gp <- ggplot(data, aes({{x}}, group = {{color}})) + 
      stat_summary(aes(y = {{y}}, fill = {{color}}),
                   fun = sum, geom = 'col', colour = 'black') + 
      theme_bw() +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA),
        legend.position = "bottom") + 
      labs(x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y), fill = substitute(color))
  
  if(missing(facet_x) & missing(facet_y)) return(gp)
  if(missing(facet_y)) return(gp + facet_grid(cols = vars(!!ensym(facet_x))))
  if(missing(facet_x)) return(gp + facet_grid(rows = vars(!!ensym(facet_y))))
  return(gp + facet_grid(rows = vars(!!ensym(facet_y)),
                         cols = vars(!!ensym(facet_x))))
}
```

This allows, for example:

```r
mtcars %>% edgeHist(cyl, hp, color = cyl, facet_x = am)
```

[image]

Or

```r
mtcars %>% edgeHist(x = cyl, y = hp, color = cyl, facet_x = am, facet_y = gear)
```

[image]

Or even without facets:

```r
iris %>% edgeHist(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

To incorporate a color palette, we could do:

```r
edgeHist <- function(data, x, y, color, facet_x, facet_y, palette) {
  
    gp <- ggplot(data, aes({{x}}, group = {{color}})) + 
      stat_summary(aes(y = {{y}}, fill = {{color}}),
                   fun = sum, geom = 'col', colour = 'black') + 
      theme_bw() +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA),
        legend.position = "bottom") + 
      labs(x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y), fill = substitute(color))
  
  if(!missing(palette)) gp <- gp + scale_fill_gradientn(colors = palette)
  if(missing(facet_x) & missing(facet_y)) return(gp)
  if(missing(facet_y)) return(gp + facet_grid(cols = vars(!!ensym(facet_x))))
  if(missing(facet_x)) return(gp + facet_grid(rows = vars(!!ensym(facet_y))))
  return(gp + facet_grid(rows = vars(!!ensym(facet_y)),
                         cols = vars(!!ensym(facet_x))))
}
```

This allows, for example:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  edgeHist(cyl, hp, cyl, facet_x = am, palette = c('red', 'orange', 'green4'))
```

[image]

Comment: The tidyverse option is very new to me, thank you for showing me how it is implemented! I will definitely start using your approach as its far simpler and does what I want in less lines of code. I was thinking about how I can make it simple and you approach is exactly what I need. Furthermore, what does ```!!ensym()``` do in this case?

Comment: In this context, `ensym` is similar to `substitute`, in that in means 'don't look for a symbol called `facet_x`, swap it for the literal symbol that was passed to the function'. The bang-bang operator `!!` is used to evaluate this part of the expression inside `vars`, otherwise `vars` would be looking for a column called `ensym(facet_x)` instead of the symbol it represents.

Comment: How I see, so it's something similar to ```eval(parse(text=facet_x))``` where we evaluate for the expression. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: On a additional note, whilst not totally related to the post. If I wanted to manually change the colours, how can I achieve this? For example, I have tried ```scale_color_manual(values=c("#8B0000", "#FFD700" ,"#0000CD"))``` but the value for `fill` in `stat_summary` overrides this each time,

Comment: @Workingdollar you need `scale_fill_maual` not `scale_color_manual`. The difference is that `color` only affects the outline color of the bars.

Comment: I have no success with this neither from the output of my plots it does not fill in the colours. I removed `fill` from stat summary, as I was getting issues with continuous/discrete scales. But no change

Comment: @Workingdollar since you have a numeric fill scale, it would actually be `scale_fill_gradient`. I'll update to show you how to incorporate this.

Comment: That is an interesting approach, turns out that I had difficulty with my method as I was using an alternative approach. The results would be the color scales from my previous comment but I got no output and I was too hasty so I did not check this out. I managed to get it working now, thank you for the interpretation!